# PreAuthorize not getting honored over ResourceServerConfigurerAdaptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Resource Server with Spring Security enabled. In Resource Server, i am extending the ResourceServerConfigurerAdaptor, some like the following.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter { 

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .anonymous().disable().requestMatcher(new OAuthRequestedMatcher()).authorizeRequests()            
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")            
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    private static class OAuthRequestedMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");               
            boolean haveOauth2Token = (auth != null) && auth.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer");
            boolean haveAccessToken = request.getParameter("access_token") != null;
            return haveOauth2Token || haveAccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i am expecting `/api/admin/**` to be accessible to ADMIN Role only.
Everything works fine till now.

But now i am trying to override this behavior at the method level using `@PreAuthorize` method level annotation.

Following is the RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/admin/event")
public class ShunyaEventResource {

    @Autowired
    private ShunyaEventService eventService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or #oauth2.hasScope('write')")
    @PostMapping
    public void createEvent(@RequestBody ShunyaEvent event, Principal user) {      
        eventService.create(event);
    }

}
```

So, i want to allow `/api/admin/event` to be accessible to `#oauth2 write` scope as well. But this does not work, unless either i remove `/api/admin/**` from antmatcher altogether or i add #oauth2.hasScope('write') in antmatcher itself.

I have already defined the below configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

Here my question is why Method Level security not working for an endpoint that is already covered by ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter? What is precedence of security filter when same endpoint is covered by MethodLevel Security (using PreAuthorize) and HttpSecurity antMatcher?

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Good question, you should start by enabling the spring security debug logs, they are quite exhaustive and will probably give you some insight. `logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG` should do it if you're using yml configuration files, just try the request afterwards. You can post logs here if it doesn't help you.

Comment: in addition to what jebeaudet, I suggest you take a look at @Order annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html

Comment: Web security and method security are two different ways to secure your application. If you use both at the same time, both rules have to pass. Your web security condition is `hasAnyRole("ADMIN")` and your method security condition is `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or #oauth2.hasScope('write')`. The resulting is `hasAnyRole("ADMIN") and (hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or #oauth2.hasScope('write'))`.